# Chromium CEFSharp connection issue

Tags: wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I've used CefSharp in my WPF application to connect to intranet website.
The connection is OK but the web page is not completely loaded, if my PC doesn't have internet connection. But from "Chrome Broswer", everything is OK.
If my PC has internet connection, the web page from my intranet website, is completely loaded. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is with another browser, do they load page correctly? CefSharp uses  Chromium core and there are differences to Google Chrome. Can it be, that data are cached in Chrome?

Comment: @Rekshino yes, if I tried with Firefox & IE(with Flash plugins), the page loaded correctly.The CEFSharp version I'm using is the latest version (CefSharp.WPF 57.0.0). If I used CEFSharp version 39.0.0 (CEFSharp.WPF 39.0.0), it's working perfectly for the same web site.

Comment: I haven't tested with other versions other than (39.0.0 & 57.0.0). For 57.0.0, I've added the following CEFSettings.

Comment: So you mean something went broken in newer version of CefSharp? Hmm..

Comment: I am not sure whether I can really say "it's broken in newer version." In v57.0.0, I've added this CefSettings. CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");
            Cef.Initialize(cefSettings); For v39.0.0, I don't need to add any CefSettings.

Comment: Is it flash, that isn't displayed?

Comment: I've tested with v49.0.0, v51.0.0 & v53.0.0, Only v49.0.0 is working. I'm testing Web-RTC hosted on the web-page.

Comment: @Rekshino no it's not flash.

Comment: I doubt it helps, but try to replace gpu-disable with cefSettings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();   Which .NET version do you use?

Comment: @Rekshino .NET v4.5.2 & v4.6.2. I'll try to replace the gpu-disable with cefSettings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs(); and let you know the result.

Comment: @Rekshino I've tried with cefSettings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs(). It's not working for CefSharp.Wpf v51.0.0 and above. But it's working for CefSharp.Wpf up to v49.0.1. Is there any breaking changes after v51.0.0?

Comment: As I can see at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases?after=v51.0.0-pre01  **"CefSharp  requires at least  .Net 4.5.2, last version to support .Net 4.0 is 49"** and " Chromium  has removed support for  Windows XP  and  Windows Vista."